# Spring security login not showing

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I'm adding Spring Security on a Spring MVC app; however, when I run the application, the Spring Security default login does not show up (not even when I browse to a link which is supposed to be "secured").

Configuration class (forgive the indentation):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConf extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserService userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("**/secured/**").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin().permitAll();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder());
}

private PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
    return new PasswordEncoder() {

        @Override
        public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
            return encode(rawPassword).equals(encodedPassword);
        }

        @Override
        public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
            return rawPassword.toString();
        }
    };
}   }
```

I also tried adding a custom login, but it does not seem to find the page (which is otherwise reachable):

```
http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("**/secured/**").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage('/login').permitAll();
```

Summing up, I need the default Spring Security login page to be displayed first, so I can test the authentication, then I need to be able to add a new login form to be displayed instead. What should I do?

EDIT: I figured out the configuration problem which prevented the Spring login to be displayed. The following tags had to be added in the web.xml file in order to integrate Spring Security with Spring MVC. Now the login is succesfully displayed.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: can you try removing the security configuration and rerun application so whole of it is secured and should ask for login

Comment: @EspringDev I'm not sure I understand what you are suggesting.

Comment: remove SecurityConf class from the project. Without it default spring security configuration will come into play. all of your application link will fall into secured context. Please check if you can see default login page then.

Comment: How could that work? Without that class, there is no Spring Security configuration at all in the project.

Comment: That will work. Adding a security configuration file is just customising the security. Without it spring boot configures default security configuration. Have you tried it atleast ??

Comment: I tried, it did not work, but it does not matter, the problem i solved now. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Can you share the resolution for helping others

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the configuration problem which prevented the Spring login to be displayed. The following tags had to be added in the web.xml file in order to integrate Spring Security with Spring MVC. Now the login is succesfully displayed.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```